# How to get a subdomain using window.location?

Tags: javascript, subdomain, hostname

If I have a hostname such as: http://sample.example.com and in Javascript I do `window.location.hostname`, would I get "example.com" or "sample.example.com"?

If not, how would I be able to get sample.example.com?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, `window.location.hostname` will give you subdomains as well. If this isn't working, or isn't supported by some other browser, you could quite easily parse for it:

```
// window.location.href == "http://sample.somedomain.com/somedir/somepage.html"
var domain = /:\/\/([^\/]+)/.exec(window.location.href)[1];
```

Comment: nickf, thanks! What is  /:\/\/([^\/]+)/ ? Regex expression to execute against?

Comment: yes: it finds everything from the first :// to the end or the next / ... this will be the subdomains, domain and tld stuff

Answer (score 24):

This does the trick for me:

```
var host = window.location.host
var subdomain = host.split('.')[0]
```

Comment: For a host/hostname that starts with `www`, this might return `www` as the subdomain.

Comment: And that's correct, because www is a subdomain after all.

Answer (score 16):

I know this is an old question but a more robust answer would be to capture all subdomains. It's possible to have nested subdomains such as `https://my.company.website.com`. In order to adequately capture all subdomains, I think this is the simplest answer:

```js
// for https://my.company.website.com,
const subdomain = window.location.hostname.split('.').slice(0, -2).join('.');
console.log(subdomain); // "my.company"
```

Comment: I like this answer because you don't care if you don't have any subdomains. this works with: `subdomain2.subdomain1.domain.com`, `subdomain.domain.com`, `domain.com`. Due to localhost, if I'm in a local environment, I would change the slice to -1

Comment: To clarify @LucasVazquez comment, in the example of `domain.com` this code will return an empty string ` `.

Comment: Doesn't work with top-level domains such as `.co.uk`

Answer (score 12):

It can be done as below:

```
var subdomain =  window.location.host.split('.')[1] ? window.location.host.split('.')[0] : false;
```

Comment: Please consider explaining your answer.

Comment: it is the seme of    x = a ? b : c ; => if 'a' exist 'x' will be = 'b' otherwise 'x' will equal 'c',, so id you call   sub.mydoman.com , (the second valu in the split with exist so it mean you have subsoman whiche is '' sub '  ) but you you call so mydoman.com  , the second part of split of location host will not exist , so it gave null . so you will have subdoman = 'false ' , by this way you can get subdomain , or false ;

Answer (score 6):

```
const subdomain = window.location.hostname.split(".")[0]
```

**window.location.hostname** return string include subdomain - main domain - ltd
so you can easily get the first word by converting it to an array then getting first item

Answer (score 5):

First of all, it's `window.location`, not `document.location` (`document.location` works in some browsers but it is not standard)

And yes, `location.hostname` *will* return the entire domain name, including any subdomains

Read more here

[Window Location](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)

Answer (score 3):

Yes alert(window.location.hostname) will include subdomains like 'www' and 'sample'.

Answer (score 2):

How about this snippet. It might help:

```
var a = new String(window.location);
a = a.replace('http://','');
a = a.substring(0, a.indexOf('/'));
alert(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

with array destructuring you can do this:

```
// window.location.host = "meta.stackoverflow.com"
const [ , , subdomain] = window.location.hostname.split(".").reverse();
// console.log(subdomain);
// "meta"
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the npm package **psl** (Public Suffix List). You can look this link: [npm psl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498592/extract-hostname-name-from-string)

Comment: This is the right way to solve it. Sub domain could have dot or dots.

Answer (score 1):

## It's a simple way to split domain parts like `subdomain.maindomain.extension`

```
// Print Subdomain
console.log(window.location.host.split('.')[0]);

// Print  Maindomain
console.log(window.location.host.split('.')[1]);

// Print  extension 
console.log(window.location.host.split('.')[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Subdomain could have dots, splitting with dot is not valid.
You can check this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/psl

These are valid subdomains.

```
www.example.com
www.foo.example.com
foo.bar.example.com
```

You can check it in your local machine if you have a server. This is working in my app
http://dev.test.foo.localhost:3000

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed something a little more versaitile so I wrote this function:

```
const getSubdomainFromHref = href => {
  let a = href.replace("http://", "").replace("https://", "");
  subdomain = a.substring(0, a.indexOf("."));
  return subdomain || "default";
};
```