# Using javascript to get sub domain from url

Tags: javascript, riak

I have a standard URL e.g.

```
http://www.test.com/test1/test2.html
```

I am using javascript in riak for map reduce and would like to only extract www.test.com.  So...the domain and the subdomain.

What is the most efficient method to do this in js since I will have millions of records?

Thanks

Comment: Tricky, you almost need a database of known domain name extensions because, what happens if you have a url like... http://www.example.co.uk? ... A list like this: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1

Comment: Well...in python I did this.  remove http:// and split by /.  This the domain was the first element.  Just need something in JS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8498629/623400

```
var matches = url.match(/^https?\:\/\/([^\/?#]+)(?:[\/?#]|$)/i);
var domain = matches && matches[1];  // domain will be null if no match is found
```

Sophisticated domain matching is kinda tricky, but all this is covered quite well in the linked post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var url = "http://www.test.com/test1/test2.html";
var domain = url.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/)[1]
```