# Is it possible to have two content scripts run on two separate pages?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

Say I have two content scripts, `codeA.js` and `codeB.js`. I am wondering if it possible to run `codeA.js` on http://www.example.com and have `codeB.js` run on http://www.domain.com.

Would it be possible to set my `content_scripts` in the `manifest.json` file to:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["http://www.example.com", "http:www.domain.com"],
        "js": ["codeA.js", "codeB.js"]
    }
]
```

and then have each script check to see which URL the page currently sits at? If so, how would I go about doing this?

**UPDATE:**
I have tried using the following code

```
if(document.location == "http://*.google.com/*" || "https://*.google.com/*") {
    alert("you are using google");
} else if(document.location == "http://*.yahoo.com/*" || "https://*.yahoo.com") {
    alert("you are using yahoo!");
}
```

but I kept getting `you are using google`.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807832/javascript-simple-regex-to-find-root-domain to match domain, your code does not work.

Comment: Related: ["How to specify which content scripts which will run on all_frames and which won't?"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15836420/331508).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that `content_scripts` is an *array*:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["http://www.example.com/*"],
        "js": ["codeA.js"]
    },
    {
        "matches": ["http://www.domain.com/*"],
        "js": ["codeB.js"]
    }
]
```

Comment: from Manifest version2?

Comment: Thanks, this works. I hadn't realized that `content_scripts` was an array. I wish they had made this clear in the `content_scripts` documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Make a single script file and check for the domain name like below

```
if(document.location == domain1){
  // load script file for domain1
} else {
  // load script for other domains
}
```

AFAIK you cannot mention different content script files for different domains in `manifest.json` file.

As per the edit of your method, that code does not work. You must check it using regular expression not just `==` as your domain contains `*` in between. And script Web Accessible Resources before hand.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer. Unfortunately, I tried your code and it didn't seem to work (see updated question). Any idea on what went wrong?

Comment: @Kootling Script files you are trying to load must be mentioned in Web Accessible Resources before hand. Have you done that? Check this https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources

Comment: Actually, that page states: `Content scripts themselves do not need to be whitelisted.` So I do not think it is a problem of whitelisting the content script.

Comment: @Kootling Ok, but have you placed regex to match domain?