# how to Get domain name of image tag from html content by javascript

Tags: javascript

I looking for way to show the domain name of images from images tag

```
<p>aabb .</p><br><center>
<img itemprop="image" src="http://subww.somedomain.com.uk/images/news/Image/2013/09/20/6523c3850ef881.img.jpg" alt="bbddd ddd" class="dddd" border="0" height="225" width="300"><br><i>lkjlkkjf</i></center>
<img src="http://www.somebbbdomain.com/images/news/Image/2013/09/20/6523c3850ef881.img.jpg" alt="bbddd ddd">
<div style="clear: both;"></div><p>aabbcc</p>
```

The javascript will look for fist src of images then extract alert domain name.. "somedomain.com.uk" to screen.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself so far? What did not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like:

```
var imgEles = document.getElementsByTagName("img"),
    pattern = /^https?\:\/\/([^\/?#]+)(?:[\/?#]|$)/i,
    domains = [];
for( var im = 0; im < imgEles.length; im++) {
   var src = imgEles[im].src;
   var matches = src.match(pattern);
   var domain = matches && matches[1]; 
   domains.push( domain );
}
console.log( domains );
```

Comment: thanhk very much .. this is great short one compair to other http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498592/extract-root-domain-name-from-string .. thanks again