# Regex Classic ASP

Tags: regex, asp-classic

I've currently got a string which contains a URL, and I need to get the base URL.

The string I have is http://www.test.com/test-page/category.html

I am looking for a RegEx that will effectively remove any page/folder names at the end. The issue is that some people may enter the domain in the following formats:

```
http://www.test.com
www.test.co.uk/
www.test.info/test-page.html
www.test.gov/test-folder/test-page.html
```

It must return http://www.websitename.ext/ each time i.e. the domain name and extension (e.g. .info .com .co.uk etc) with a forward slash at the end.

Effectively it needs to return the base URL, without any page/folder names. Is there any easy way to do with with a Regular Expression?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**My approach:** Use a **RegEx** to extract the **domain name**. Then add `http:` to the front and `/` to the end. Here's the RegEx:

```
^(?:http:\/\/)?([\w_]+(?:\.[\w_]+)+)(?=(?:\/|$))
```

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8498629/1497596) to the question [Extract root domain name from string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8498592/1497596). *(It left me somewhat disatisfied, although pointed out the need to account for **`https`**, the **port number**, and **user authentication info** which my RegEx does **not** do.)*

Here is an implementation in **VBScript**. I put the RegEx in a constant and defined a function named `GetDomainName()`. You should be able to incorporate that function in your ASP page like this:

```vb
normalizedUrl = "http://" & GetDomainName(url) & "/"
```

You can also test my script from the command prompt by saving the code to a file named `test.vbs` and then passing it to `cscript`:

```
cscript test.vbs
```

**Test Program**

```vb
Option Explicit

Const REGEXPR = "^(?:http:\/\/)?([\w_]+(?:\.[\w_]+)+)(?=(?:\/|$))"
'                    ^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^       ^^^^
'                        A         B1         B2            C
'
' A  - An optional 'http://' scheme
' B1 - Followed by one or more alpha-numeric characters
' B2 - Followed optionally by one or more occurences of a string
'      that begins with a period that is followed by
'      one or more alphanumeric characters, and
' C  - Terminated by a slash or nothing.

Function GetDomainName(sUrl)
   Dim oRegex, oMatch, oMatches, oSubMatch

   Set oRegex = New RegExp
   oRegex.Pattern = REGEXPR
   oRegex.IgnoreCase = True
   oRegex.Global = False
   Set oMatches = oRegex.Execute(sUrl)

   If oMatches.Count > 0 Then
       GetDomainName = oMatches(0).SubMatches(0)
   Else
       GetDomainName = ""
   End If
End Function

Dim Data : Data = _
    Array( _
            "xhttp://www.test.com" _
          , "http://www..test.com" _
          , "http://www.test.com." _
          , "http://www.test.com" _
          , "www.test.co.uk/" _
          , "www.test.co.uk/?q=42" _
          , "www.test.info/test-page.html" _
          , "www.test.gov/test-folder/test-page.html" _
          , ".www.test.co.uk/" _
          )

Dim sUrl, sDomainName
For Each sUrl In Data
    sDomainName = GetDomainName(sUrl)

    If sDomainName = "" Then
        WScript.Echo "[ ] [" & sUrl & "]"
    Else
        WScript.Echo "[*] [" & sUrl & "] => [" & sDomainName & "]"
    End If
Next
```

**Expected Output:**

```
[ ] [xhttp://www.test.com]
[ ] [http://www..test.com]
[ ] [http://www.test.com.]
[*] [http://www.test.com] => [www.test.com]
[*] [www.test.co.uk/] => [www.test.co.uk]
[*] [www.test.co.uk/?q=42] => [www.test.co.uk]
[*] [www.test.info/test-page.html] => [www.test.info]
[*] [www.test.gov/test-folder/test-page.html] => [www.test.gov]
[ ] [.www.test.co.uk/]
```

Comment: I update the regex to "^(?:http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?([\w_|-]+(?:\.[\w_|-]+)+)(?=(?:\/|$))", now it accepts https/http and hifen "-" in the subdomain

Answer (score 0):

I haven't coded Classic ASP in 12 years and this is totally untested.

```
result = "http://" & Split(Replace(url, "http://",""),"/")(0) & "/"
```