# jquery - Get middle portion of URL path

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

URL Examples:

```
http://www.demotest.com/categoey/t23
http://demotest.com/categoey/t23
http://www.demotest.net/categoey/c24
```

I only want "**demotest**" portion from above URL (using jquery and JavaScript )

Using **window.location.hostname** I got full path **www.demotest.com** but i want only **demotest** part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this regular expression:

```
\.([^.]+)\.[^.]+$
```

http://regex101.com/r/eM7oQ0

Or you could split:

```
var domain = window.location.hostname.split('.');
console.log(domain[domain.length - 2]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jyWYu/

Comment: its working on www.demotest.com  but sometime url does not contain www portion........ so url only demotest.com

Answer (score 0):

Try using split,

```
urlParts = window.location.hostname.split('.');
urlParts[urlParts.length-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.location.hostname.split('.')[0]`

more at [Extract hostname name from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498592/extract-root-domain-name-from-string)

Answer (score 0):

Split it by "." like so:

```
var str = "www.demotest.com"
var arrStr = str.split(".");
```

Then what you want will be at index 1 - `arrStr[1]`

Here is jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/N0ir/yLtCW/