# Regex to get the domain from URL, and thing

Tags: javascript, regex

There are lots of posts online like this, but none of them seem to do what I'm trying to do.

Let's say I have a domain in a string:

[Extract hostname name from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498592/extract-root-domain-name-from-string)

And I want to extract the domain name and nothing else (not the protocol, the subdomain or the file extension).

so for

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498592/extract-root-domain-name-from-string
```

I want to get:

```
stackoverflow.com
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: first log message in this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/736970

Comment: As the post you are linking to suggests, it is usually a good idea to rely on a solid URL parsing function and then just keep the part you need. In terms of performance the difference will be negligible, and you'll gain in reusability and readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this on:

```
var url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498592/extract-root-domain-name-from-string';
var domain = url.match(/^https?:\/\/([^\/?#]+)/)[1];
alert(domain);
```

This looks for a string that starts with `http` and optionally `s`, followed by `://`, then matches everything it can that is not a `/`. But `.match()` returns an array here:

```
['http://stackoverflow.com', 'stackoverflow.com']
```

So, we use `[1]` to get the submatch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple regex like this:

```
\/\/(.*?)\/
```

Here you have a working example:

http://regex101.com/r/iP0uX7/1

Hope to help