# What do {curly braces} around javascript variable name mean

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

**EDIT**
After looking at JSHint I found this '**destructuring expression' is available in ES6 (use esnext option) or Mozilla JS extensions (use moz)** and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7)  however after reading it I still don't understand why it is used

I have come across the following code on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/ui)

```
var ui = require("sdk/ui");
var { ActionButton } = require("sdk/ui/button/action");
```

What do the braces on the second line do and why are they used? Why are there no braces on the first line?

Comment: I think that's an EcmaScript 6 destructuring binding pattern.

Comment: @Pointy after looking at JSHint I found this 'destructuring expression' is available in ES6 (use esnext option) or Mozilla JS extensions (use moz) and this however after reading it I still don't understand why it is used https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7

Comment: @Bergi surely closing this as a duplicate of a pre-ES6 question whose answers claim that this is a JS 1.7 feature unique to Firefox isn't helpful? The world has changed since that question was asked and the answers there are obsolete - plus this question is drawing far more views. We should improve this Q&A pair to clearly include the history of this syntax so that nobody gets confused about the relationship between JS 1.7 and ES 6, then close the *other* question as a duplicate of *this* one.

Comment: @MarkAmery: Both these questions *ask* about the JS 1.7 feature, and are even tagged [tag:firefox]. For ES6 questions, I'm using [Javascript object bracket notation on left side to assign](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26999820/1048572) as the canonical question.

Comment: @Bergi Hmm. Given the context in which he found this code, you're clearly right that the code the OP was reading was using the JS 1.7 feature, but I think the OP in this case has come across this syntax and *doesn't know* which version of the syntax he's seeing. Wouldn't it be more useful to have a comprehensive duplicate target that explains that there are two specifications that introduce the syntax (as well as any differences between the two, although I think they're identical and the ES spec just copied the JavaScript 1.7 version exactly)?

Comment: @MarkAmery: Sure, go ahead, you'll have my support for creating a new canonical post.

Comment: This question is marked as a duplicate but it is better formulated and much more googlable and even has a better answer.

Answer (score 330, accepted):

This is what's known as a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), and it's a new feature of [JavaScript 1.7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7) (and [ECMAScript 6](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-destructuring-assignment)) (Currently, only available as part of the Firefox JavaScript engine.)  Roughly, it would translate into this:

```
var ActionButton = require("sdk/ui/button/action").ActionButton;
```

It seems silly in this example, as there's only one item being assigned.  However, you'd be able to use this pattern to assign multiple variables at once:

```
{x, y} = foo;
```

Is the equivalent to:

```
x = foo.x;
y = foo.y;
```

This can also be used for arrays.  For example, you could easily swap two values without using a temporary variable:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 3;

[a, b] = [b, a];
```

---

Browser support can be tracked using [kangax' ES6 compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#destructuring).

Comment: Should `ActionButton = ...` be `var ActionButton = ...`? This example wouldn't declare a global -- right?

Comment: A much more useful example would be something like `{width, height, color} = options`, which would replace the lines `width = options.width; height = options.height; color = options.color`.

Comment: Or an inside out object.

Comment: @CaseyFalk - From what I can tell, `var {x, y} = ...` would be the equivalent of `var x = ...` and `var y = ...` and `{x, y} = ...` would be the equivalent of `x = ...` and `y = ...`

Comment: @CaseyFalk - In other words, you're right.  Since the example above was declaring `{ ActionButton }`, my *rough translation* was incorrect.  I've updated it.

Comment: I realize it was "rough" -- sorry to be nit-picky. : ) Have an upvote.

Comment: "JavaScript 1.7 support was introduced in Firefox 2 (October 2006)" :D Anyway, it is part of the ECMA-6 draft ([assignment](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-destructuring-assignment), [binding](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-destructuring-binding-patterns)), so it will [get broader browser support](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=811#c15) in the foreseeable future. Also: `(function(arg1, {opt1, opt2}) { console.log(arg1, opt1, opt2); })(1, {opt1: 2, opt2: 3})`. Also: `var {ActionButton: ab} = ...;`

Comment: Is the last example still destructuring, since it uses brackets instead of curly braces?

Comment: The first is an example of destructuring objects, the second is an example of destructuring arrays.

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/

Comment: Your last example switching values of two variables: Looks very neat, but to say 'without using a temporary variable" is a little misleading as you are implicitly creating an array containing the two values taken from the variables, then assigning those values back to the original variables. So, aren't you actually creating a temporary array plus two temporary variables? Wouldn't it be faster simply to use one temporary variable?

Comment: This will also work piecemeal.  I had a function which returned a large complex object.  I only needed one piece of that.  e.g. function returned `{client: abc, db: xyz}`   In my call to the function I used `const {client} = await functionCall()` and just got the small piece I needed. [reference](https://maxcode.online/nextjs-mongodb-integration-with-api-routes/)

Comment: Currently, `{x, y} = foo` is not valid (results in SyntaxError), but you can have `let {x, y} = foo` (or const or var instead of let) and `({x, y} = foo)` (with parentheses).

Comment: So JavaScript now basically has the same mechanics as Python's tuple unpacking?