# Is var { Route, Redirect, RouteHandler, Link } = Router; valid in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

What does this mean in Javascript ? 
I found this in **react-router** examples

```
var { Route, Redirect, RouteHandler, Link } = Router;
```

I get the following error when it is run through browserify.

```
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"
```

https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/examples/dynamic-segments/app.js

Esprima also gives the same error:
http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html

Comment: Where exactly do you see that example (link please)?  It clearly isn't legal javascript, but it is probably useful to explain what it is or what it is intended to be used for (or perhaps just a mistake).

Comment: see the example here: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/examples/dynamic-segments/app.js

Comment: That linked example is most definitely not Javascript, so there is clearly some other parser (apparently [JSX](http://jsx.github.io/)) that runs before any JS interpreter sees that code.

Comment: tl;dr: Yes it is valid JavaScript, but it's not supported by all browsers yet. See http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#destructuring .

Comment: I also want to add that you can use ES6 features when using JSX because the JSX transpiler understands them and converts them to ES5. However, you can also use ES6 features today with JSX: https://github.com/esnext/esnext .

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Apparently it's called a destructuring assignment.

From another post here:

```
{x, y} = foo;
```

is equivalent to

```
x = foo.x;
y = foo.y;
```

This is part of ECMAScript 6, and Facebook's JSX transform has an optional flag to enable transpiling select ES6 syntax (including destructuring) to ES5-compatible syntax, which [react-router uses](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/9e58e7daab97597869846b49e41762fb9f23fa4a/webpack.config.js#L38).

Here is the original post with answer by Mike Christensen:

[What do {curly braces} around javascript variable name mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187903/what-do-curly-braces-around-javascript-variable-name-mean)

Comment: I was about to say.. this isn't a JSX specific syntax as far as I can see... Firefox javascript feature huh?

Comment: @BrettCaswell: http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-destructuring-assignment

Comment: yeah.. I caught that.. updated this post with that link (which came from MDN page)

Comment: hmm.. @OJay, I don't know about you.. but when I click on a link that says specification, I don't expect to see a wiki page.. still, nice site.. thanks

Comment: Frustrating how casually destructuring is used without concern for people trying to follow a tutorial which is supposedly for newbies.

Answer (score 1):

It worked after changing my code to

```
var Route = Router.Route;
var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;
var Link = Router.Link;
```

More information about this can be found here: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html#transferring-with-...-in-jsx

Comment: It's not JSX. It's JavaScript. http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-destructuring-assignment

Answer (score 0):

That's a [JSX](http://facebook.github.io/jsx/) file, not JavaScript. It was invented by Facebook as part of [React.js](http://facebook.github.io/react/). It gets compiled into a JavaScript file before execution. The file had @jsx pragma in the previous commit: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/commit/3abe98444481598beef22d3af2bf01effc556c6b

JSX allows to do things like this:

```
// Using JSX to express UI components.
var dropdown =
  <Dropdown>
    A dropdown list
    <Menu>
      <MenuItem>Do Something</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem>Do Something Fun!</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem>Do Something Else</MenuItem>
    </Menu>
  </DropDown>;

render(dropdown);
```

and this

```
var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
});

React.render(<HelloMessage name="John" />, mountNode);
```

Comment: `var { Route, Redirect, RouteHandler, Link } = Router;` is not JSX. Your answer doesn't seem to address this at all.

Comment: @FelixKling that's it. Take a look at the last commit comment and render method in the middle of the document topic caster references.

Comment: @FelixKling I updated my answer with a link to previous commit that contains jsx pragma tag.

Comment: Not sure what your point is. Only because `var { Route, Redirect, RouteHandler, Link } = Router;` is used together with JSX doesn't make it JSX. What may be confusing to people is that one can use ES6 features because the JSX compiler understands them and converts them to ES5.

Comment: @FelixKling the point is the code file referenced by the post author gets compiled by JSX-compiler into a JavaScript file that can be executed across all browsers, not in FireFox only. JSX syntax is similar to ECMAScript6 in many aspects, but the file referenced uses many other features of JSX and it's incorrectly to say that this is ECMAScript6. It handles html markup as JSX do, not ECMAScript6. Your response is absolutely correct without a link to the source file.

Comment: *"JSX syntax is similar to ECMAScript6 in many aspects"* Not all. JSX is just a *syntax extension for JavaScript*, not a language itself. The extension is rather small: http://facebook.github.io/jsx/ . The part the OP is asking about is ECMAScript 6 for all intends and purposes.

Comment: @FelixKling where do you see a reference to ECMA6 in the question?

Comment: Destructuring, `var { Route, Redirect, RouteHandler, Link } = Router;`, is an ES6 feature. It is *not* part of JSX. That's what I mean.