# JavaScript: var {left, ...props} = this.props;

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I was reading the source code of Facebook's fixed-data-table, and i found [this](https://github.com/facebook/fixed-data-table/blob/master/src/FixedDataTableCellGroup.react.js#L161)

```
var {left, ...props} = this.props;
```

What that it means? is this a new semantic? I'm confused o.O

Comment: It's ES6 destructuring assignment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is var { Route, Redirect, RouteHandler, Link } = Router; valid in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136394/is-var-route-redirect-routehandler-link-router-valid-in-javascript)

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy, It's not quite a duplicate because the other question doesn't mention rest destructuring.

Comment: It's not part of a standard yet and best described in React docs: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a special form of destructuring assignment [proposed for ES7](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread) (and eagerly implemented in the jsx tools and Babel).  It creates two variables: `left`, and `props`.

`left` has the value of `this.props.left`.

`props` is an object with all of the other properties of `this.props` (excluding `left`).

If you wrote it without destructuring it'd look like this:

```
var left = this.props.left;
var props = {};

Object.keys(this.props).forEach(function(key, index){
    if (key !== 'left') {
        props[key] = this.props[key];
    }
}, this);
```

That's more than a few characters shaved off :-)

Comment: Can you provide a link for this type of "rest destructuring"? It doesn't work in Traceur for me at least.

Comment: https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-destructuring-assignment (edit: and 12.14.5.4)

Comment: This reference does not describe the syntax here. It describes a syntax for destructuring assignment involving arrays, as in `var [a, ...b] = [1, 2, 3]`. I've never seen the syntax shown here, which is not to say it doesn't exist...

Comment: ObjectAssignmentPattern has a AssignmentPropertyList has a AssignmentProperty has a AssignmentElement has a DestructuringAssignmentTarget.

Comment: Any idea why Traceur chokes on that? Any ES6 processors that support it? Why do resources such as http://www.2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html not mention that? What name would this syntax be given in the kangax compatibility tables?

Comment: I could be wrong.  It is supported in the jsx compiler, and 6to5 (now called babel).

Comment: 6to5 gives me a syntax error on the line in question. However, it works with the `--experimental` flag. I think it may be purely a JSX extension, or ES7 thing, in which case people should be warned away from it. I have no idea if there's any discussion about actually adding this syntax to the spec, but personally it seems weird to me, since I always thought of rest and spread as being fundamentally about array elements.

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread. It says "It is a Stage 1 proposal for ECMAScript 7."

Comment: Thanks for the catch, I updated the answer with your link and explanation.  What I saw in the spec was referring to `var {a, d: {b, c}} = x;` (I think)

Comment: torazaburo thanks you clued me into the need to add a special babel plugin to get it to work: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/