# What do curly braces around a variable in a function parameter mean

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, curly-braces

I saw this code on a package:

```
const SortableList = SortableContainer(({items}) => {
 return (
     <ul>
        {items.map((value, index) =>
            <SortableItem key={`item-${index}`} index={index} value={value} />
        )}
    </ul>
 );
});
```

What is happening to `items` by putting curly braces around it in the function parameters?

Comment: @KevinB what does it mean in JSX?

Comment: eh, good point. that particular place isn't jsx, jsx is the `( <ul>` portion.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Pulling_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) syntax.

As another example, the following two lines of code are equal:

```
const { items } = args

const items = args.items
```

Simply put, it is a simplified way of accessing specific field of a given variable for further use in that scope.

In your original example, it is declaring a variable `items` for use in the function body that is the `items` field of that first argument.

```
const SortableList = SortableContainer(({items}) => {
    // do stuff with items here
```

is equal to

```
const SortableList = SortableContainer((input) => {
    const items = input.items
    // do stuff with items here
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is likely a repost: [What do {curly braces} around javascript variable name mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187903/what-do-curly-braces-around-javascript-variable-name-mean)

But as an answer, it's [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). If your object being passed in mirrors the variable being referenced, you can retrieve that specific field during assignment.

Answer (score 2):

This is [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

In this example below, the variables **"name"**, **"sex"** and **"age"** in **curly braces "{}"** extract the values **"John"**, **"Male"** and **"24"** from **"data"** respectively:

****The variable names in **curly braces "{}"** must be same as the key names in "data"***

```js
const data = { name: "John", sex: "Male", age: 24 };

const { name, sex, age } = data; 

console.log(name); // John
console.log(sex);  // Male
console.log(age);  // 24
```

If the variable names in **curly braces "{}"** are not same as the key names in **"data"**, the values of **"undefined"** are assigned:

```js
const data = { name: "John", sex: "Male", age: 24 };

const { myName, mySex, age } = data; 

console.log(myName); // undefined
console.log(mySex);  // undefined
console.log(age);    // 24
```

The order of the variables in **curly braces "{}"** doesn't matter:

```js
const data = { name: "John", sex: "Male", age: 24 };

const { age, sex, name } = data; 

console.log(name); // John
console.log(sex);  // Male
console.log(age);  // 24
```

You can rename the variables in **curly braces "{}"**:

```js
const data = { name: "John", sex: "Male", age: 24 };

const { name: firstName, sex: gender, age } = data; 

console.log(firstName); // John
console.log(gender);    // Male
console.log(age);       // 24
```

After renaming the variables in **curly braces "{}"**, the original variables don't work and give error:

```js
const data = { name: "John", sex: "Male", age: 24 };

const { name: firstName, sex: gender, age } = data; 

console.log(name);
console.log(sex);
console.log(age);
```