# What does this assignment do in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What does this assignment do in javascript? I couldn't find any documentation about it.

```
const { name, email } = request.body;
```

Comment: Object destructuring: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/

Comment: It's called Object Destructuring. [See this stackoverflow thread for an explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187903/what-do-curly-braces-around-javascript-variable-name-mean)

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't search it due to lack of proper query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In more modern versions of ES/JS, it is roughly equivalent to

```
const name = request.body.name;
const email = request.body.email;
```

It is known as [Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring).