# What does the assignment within curly braces mean?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm new to typescript and I came across this block of code:

```
visitFieldDefinition(field) {
    const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = field;
   // rest of the code
    ....
  }
```

I read about [destructuring assigment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187903/what-do-curly-braces-around-javascript-variable-name-mean) which seems fine. But what does `{resolve = defaultFieldResolver}` mean here?

Comment: Exactly what the name of the variable hints at: [it's a default value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values_2).

Comment: So `resolve` will take on the value `defaultFieldResolver ` if `field.resolve` is `undefined` or `null` ?

Comment: Only if it is `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that `resolve` will take the value `defaultFieldResolver` in the case it is `undefined` in `field`. Otherwise it will take the value given in `field`.