# Why code inside brackets work in typescript / es6?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

i begin telling you that this code work, bu i can not find documentation about the use of code inside {}. The useStore is only a hooks in react

```
//React ES6+ Typescript

const MyComp= (props: MyCompProps) => {
let state1 = null;
let action1 = null;
{
    const {state, actions} = useStore1(mapState1,FnActions1);
    state1 = state;
    action1 = actions;
}
let state2 = null;
let action2 = null;
{
    const {state, actions} = useStore2(mapState2,FnActions2);
    state2 = state;
    action2 = actions;
}
.....
}
```

in orginal my code was:

```
const {state1, action1} = useStore1(mapState1,FnActions1);
const {state2 , action2 } =  useStore2(mapState2,FnActions2);
```

but typescript noted me a error **Error:(57, 26) TS2459: Type 'StoreProps<{ error: any; loading: any; isFetching: any; }  Pr...' has no property 'actions' and no string index signature.**
but using the first pasted code, work fine. But why?where i can find documentation about this use of code inside {...} ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do {curly braces} around javascript variable name mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187903/what-do-curly-braces-around-javascript-variable-name-mean)

Comment: show the source code of both useStore1 and useStore2!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## This is Object Destructuring

#### Why this works?

```js
const {state, actions} = useStore1(mapState1,FnActions1);
```

This works because useStore1(...) is returning a object which has two properties with **exact names** "state", "actions" inside it. So javascript is able to destructure the object and create two const for you.

#### Why this doesn't works

```js
const {state1, action1} = useStore1(mapState1,FnActions1);
```

It tries to find **"state1" and "action1"** in the returned object **{state, action}** and thus, it's not able to find these fields. Hence it's throwing the error.

More On destructing in JS - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: thanks, also the answer of @Mario vernari was correct, but you have explained me.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your second snippet as follows:

```
const {state:state1, actions:action1} = useStore1(mapState1,FnActions1);
const {state:state2 , actions:action2 } =  useStore2(mapState2,FnActions2);
```

which basically destructures and creates an alias for the fields, all at once.

Comment: Thanks Mario, your answer it's correct but is without "why" for me important to undestand

Answer (score -2):

{} Mark is common in programming language. It help you scoping the code within the block {}. Any variables defined within the block will be available just in that block.

reference: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Programming_Languages/Scoping_with_Blocks

I think your useStore1 and useStore2 return an object with structured like :

```
const useStore1 = (mapState, fnAction) => {
   // ... logic
   return {
      state, 
      actions
   }
}
```

Call to this useStore1 function will also return {state, action}. So to get the value you have to use

```
const {state, action} = useStore1(mapState1,FnActions1);
```

But your second pasted code, it write const {state1, action1}. While the useState1 return {state, action}.
Thats why your second pasted code, will produced an error.

The first pasted code not produced an error because of the block scoped code.

```
{
const {state, action} = useState1(...);
// variable state and action just available within this block.
}
```

Another approach is:

```
const stateReturn1 = useStore1(mapState1,FnActions1);
const stateReturn2 = useStore2(mapState2,FnActions2); 
state1 = stateReturn1.state;
action1 = stateReturn1.actions;
state2 = stateReturn2.state;
action2 = stateReturn2.actions;
```

Comment: {} are block delimiter, but are also used  for object destructuring. With your code, you declare two times the same const.