# what is the difference between passing an object with a variable and a lone variable to a react native component?

Tags: react-native

My lack of success in this problem may be due to a lack of proper terminology when Googling it but nonetheless I am completely stumped. I am passing an onPress function to a custom component in react native. When I pass it by itself as:

```
export const AddMorePlants = ( onPress ) => {
    return (
        <TouchableHighlight
            onPress={onPress}>
.
.
.
}
```

I get a ***this2.props.onPress is not a function*** error but when I have the exact same code except with the onPress passed within curly braces:

```
export const AddMorePlants = ({ onPress }) => {
    return (
        <TouchableHighlight
            onPress={onPress}>
.
.
.
}
```

It Works!

Why does the second one work and not the first?

Sorry for a kind of basic question I just have been really Googling and cant figure it out. Thanks in advance and I can provide any more info if needed.

Comment: according to first one 
function should be call like `AddMorePlants(direction function pass here)`
for second 
function should be call like `AddMorePlants({onPress: function defination pass like this})`
may this is a reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A functional component in React only has one parameter. The `props`. You can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

So what your first attempt at passing the `onPress` function actually looks like is:

```
export const AddMorePlants = (props) => {
   return (
       <TouchableHighlight onPress={props}/>
   );
}
```

When the `TouchableOpacity` tries to execute the method, it hits the *is not a function* error because `props` is an object.

When you do:

```
export const AddMorePlants = ({onPress}) => {
   return (
       <TouchableHighlight onPress={onPress}/>
   );
}
```

what you are doing is something called [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and it's equivalent of doing:

```
export const AddMorePlants = (props) => {
   const {onPress} = props;
   return (
       <TouchableHighlight onPress={onPress}/>
   );
}
```

By putting the brackets inside the parentheses you are just doing a shorthand version of this destructuring assignment that we have mentioned.

Here's another version that would also work:

```
export const AddMorePlants = (props) => {
   return (
       <TouchableHighlight onPress={props.onPress}/>
   );
}
```

As you can see there are many ways to access an object's property.

The important part is to remember that the `props` object is the only parameter passed into a functional component.

I hope this helps you understand what's going on there.

Answer (score 0):

In the first function you need to pass only one param i.e *onPress* to your component while in second you are [destructuring assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187903/what-do-curly-braces-around-javascript-variable-name-mean) so you are doing something like `onPress = this.props.onPress` and passing an object of params.