# I am not able to use ipfs

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, ipfs, js-ipfs, decentralized-applications

I want to publish files on ipfs but it's showing me an error.

Here is my code...

```
const ipfsClient = require('ipfs-http-client');
const ipfs = ipfsClient({host: 'ipfs.infura.io', port: 5001, protocol: 
'https'});

function App() {
const [buffer, setBuffer] = useState();

const handleChange = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  const reader = new window.FileReader();
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  reader.onloadend = () =>{
    setBuffer(reader.result);
  }

}

const handleSubmit = async(event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('submitting...')
    await ipfs.add({buffer}, (error, result) => {
      console.log('ipfs results');
      if(error){
        console.error(error);
        return;
      }
    });
}
```

I am getting this error in browser...

> TypeError: ipfsClient is not a function

Comment: Error is telling u the truth, u are using ipfsClient as function where it is not defined as a function.

Comment: @M.Mavini So what should i do, in documentation and tutorials everybody is using the same way.

Comment: Don't know it must be a funny mistake somewhere, can't help.

Comment: @M.Mavini i use "npm install ipfs-http-client" to install ipfs package, is that right?

Comment: I also clone a github project which is running in his computer, but showing same error in mine

Comment: I totally got confused, please help if you can do any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be some breaking changes. Most probably the copy of the example you have are old version. If you visit the latest readme, the new version should be initiated with:

```
import { create } from 'ipfs-http-client'
const client = create()
const client = create(new URL('http://127.0.0.1:5002'))
const { cid } = await client.add('Hello world!')
```

You can rollback to use the old version by specifiying the version no @, i.e. `npm install ipfs-http-client@42.0.0`. Instead of `npm install ipfs-http-client` which always pull the latest version (53.X now).

It's also possible to view your installed version in 'package.json' file to see the version you are using and *edit with the version you need*, '*delete node_modules*' folder and re-run `npm install`. But this requires you to save, which needs a parameter -s, so to run is `npm install -s ipfs-http-client`

Version 42, sample code should be the one you are using 'https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/tree/v42.0.0'.

Version 53(or the official 1.0 release), tells that there is a breaking change if you visit the official github site; where ipfs-http-client requires a create() and not to be used directly.

Comment: Nice to know it works, there's some tiny learning to npm(package manager). If you're interested in nodeJS, NPM is worth investing and pretty straight-forward.

Comment: Thanks but, i knew it already, tell something new. 

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with ipfs but i checked the official docs and they have done the first line like this:

```
const { CID } = require('ipfs-http-client')
```

Those brackets are essential

[What do {curly braces} around javascript variable name mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187903/what-do-curly-braces-around-javascript-variable-name-mean)