# How can I extract text from the middle of a string with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have these strings:

```
baseUrl = "http://www.example.com"
baseUrl = "https://secure.example-server.com:443"
```

Can someone tell me how I can extract the server information from baseUrl so I can get either "example" and "example-server"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I parse a URL into hostname and path in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736513/how-do-i-parse-a-url-into-hostname-and-path-in-javascript)

Comment: Regex. Just a regex.

Comment: [Posible Duplicate] here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498592/extract-root-domain-name-from-string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498592/extract-root-domain-name-from-string). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `regex`:

```
baseUrl.match(/\.(.*?)\.co/i)[1];
```

**Regex Explanation**

1. `/`: Delimiters of `regex`
2. `\.`: Matches `.` literal(need to be escaped)
3. `()`: Capturing group
4. `.*?`: Match any string
5. `co`: Matches string `co`
6. `i`: Match in-case-sensitive
7. `[1]`: Get the capturing group

**Regex Visualization**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can split strings at certain chars with split("."); (see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)
then you can compare the results to your predefined words.

or you take the 2nd element of the results which would usually(?) be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to this free library: http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to extract string between two `'.'`s (or Domain name in `URL`), you can try this:

```
var firstDotPos = baseUrl.indexOf(".");
var secondDotPos = baseUrl.indexOf(".",firstDotPos);
var yourString = baseUrl.substring(firstDotPos + 1, 18);
console.log(yourString )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split it into an array with `split()` and extract the required one with `slice()`   as follows:

### Input

```
baseUrl = "http://www.example.com"
baseUrl2 = "https://secure.example-server.com:443"
const base = baseUrl.split(".")
const base2 = baseUrl2.split(".")
console.log("Array1 :: ",base)
console.log("Array2 : ",base2)
console.log(base.slice(-2,-1))
console.log(base2.slice(-2,-1))
```

### Output

```
Array1 :: ["http://www","example","com"]
Array2 : ["https://secure","example-server","com:443"]
["example"]
["example-server"]
```