# Show 'Div X' when site loads, but not when user redirects from sub page X to home?

Tags: cookies, session-cookies

I've created a site that, when the homepage `index.html` loads, it shows an opening animation. Not something spectacular, but repeated seeing of it could become very annoying.

Currently, whenever an user opens `index.html` he/she sees the animation. That includes typing the URL, navigating from Google or from any internal page.

Is there a way to set so that when a user navigates to the URL manually (or via Google, etc.) the animation (div X) is shown, but when the user navigates from /contact back to /home (index.html) the animation is NOT shown?

This would greatly reduce over and over seeing the animation and improve the experience.

*I don't mind if the animation is shown again when the user refreshes the browser. The user should see the animation again everytime he opens a new session; thus after he closed and reopens the website. It should only apply to the current session.*

Answer (score 0):

Applying the `extractDomain()` function from **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498592/extract-root-domain-name-from-string)** to `document.referrer` (about which you should **[read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer)**) and then comparing its result to your domain name should tell you where the user came from.

Then again, this method is far from reliable. Instead I'd recommend creating a cookie when they first visit. By doing that, you can check if your user already has a cookie: if they don't, play the intro and create a cookie, and if they do, don't show it.

If you're wondering about how to implement such a function, read **[this answer about creating and reading cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie)**.