# Check if href equals a certain value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently im looping through links in a page and checking if the link contains a string to determine the url. Heres my current code:

```
$( ".domain a" ).each( function () {

                if ($(this).is(':contains("imgur")')) {
```

This can detect if the  element contains the string "imgur", but because of this is a link goes to a site like `slimgur.com`, it will also return true.

How can I properly check that the url is, in this example, `imgur.com` or any of its subdomains (`i.imgur.com` & `m.imgur.com`) and that a url such as `slimgur.com` wont return true?

Comment: Something like 'new String("imgur.com").valueOf() == new String("a").valueOf()' or maybe === imgur.com

Comment: put a `//` in front of it??

Comment: `is(':contains("://imgur.com")')`?

Comment: @JamesWilkins what would adding `://` do..?

Comment: Match the domain name part of `http://imgur.com/...`

Comment: @JamesWilkins I guess that would work, but i'd have to add multiple statements to check for imgurs direct images..(i.imgur.com) and its mobile versions as well..(m.imgur.com). Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Then perhaps you should be mentioning that in your question as well. ;)

Comment: @JamesWilkins was kinda implied but edited the OP anyway.

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed the "subdomains" part.

Comment: @Orbit subdomains should also return true or only the domain?

Comment: @BerozaPaul subdomains should return true. So for the domain `imgur.com`, `i.imgur.com` and `m.imgur.com` should all return true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
$( ".domain a" ).each( function() {
    var str = 'imgur';
    if($(this)[0].hostname.split('.').indexOf(str) > -1) {
       console.log('Found ' + str);
    }       
})
```

Comment: What does `$(this)[0]` do? Simply using `this.hostname` seems to work as well.

Comment: Inside the loop(each) $(this) is a jQuery object. But hostname works with javascript object. I just made Javascript object from jQuery object using $(this)[0]. So in here $(this)[0] = this

Comment: Ah ok. Accepting this as the answer as it programmatically includes all subdomains and seems to be the cleanest solution for my situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Rather than check the text, use the properties associated to an `<a>` tag like `hostname`.

```
$( ".domain a" ).filter(function(){
   return this.hostname === 'imgur.com';
}).doSomething();
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ysnswasy/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dykr7q64/4/)

```
$('a').each(function () {
    var url = "yahoo.com";
    var anchor = $(this).attr('href');
    var domain = url_domain(anchor);

    if (url === domain) {
       //Do something here
    }
});

function url_domain(data) {
  var    a      = document.createElement('a');
         a.href = data;
  return a.hostname;
}
```

`url_domain()` function found here: [Extract hostname name from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498592/extract-root-domain-name-from-string)

Comment: would need to know exact url to be able to match, OP seems only interested in domain. Example seems too trivialized

Comment: Yep, it looks like this would only match to a specific url. For example with imgur, image urls have a random string attached to the url so a hardcoded variable wouldnt really work.