# Can this be written in a switch statement?

Tags: javascript, micro-optimization

I am writing a Safari extension, and would like to detect what page (url) I am currently on, and do things accordingly.

Right now my code looks something like:

```
if (linkHas("facebook.com")) {...}
else if (linkHas("google.com")) {...}
else if (linkHas("yahoo.com")) {...}
```

where `linkHas()` is a function that basically returns 1 if it has the parameter, and 0 otherwise.

Is it possible to write this one single switch statement? I've read somewhere that switch statements are implemented as hash tables if there are more than 5 options. For a small script like mine, the speed probably doesn't really matter much here, I'm really just trying it as an exercise.

Comment: Is it `linkHas("example.com")` verbatim or more like `var url = getCurrentUrl();if(linkHas(url)){...}`?

Comment: The definition of linkHas is: `function linkHas(url) { return window.location.href.indexOf(url) == -1 ? false : true }` or 0 and 1 depending on how you want.

Comment: Not the definition of the function, how you call it. Do you get the string `"facebook.com"` from somewhere else as in a variable or does your code look like what you have posted wher every call of `linkHas()` gets the URL typed in directly or do you read the URLs from a list in the program?

Comment: URLs are all typed in by myself.

Comment: Than abandon all hope. You may give Merott's example a try, it's ok for a small list. For longer lists (a couple of hundreds or even thousands) you may overthink the very basics of your method.

Comment: Lol.  
Are you sure you aren't misunderstanding anything? I don't understand why you say I have to abandon hope.

Answer (score 6):

The simple, and straight answer is **no**.

The `switch` expression has to be/return a value, that is evaluated against the value of each `case`. As JCOC611 has actually demonstrated, it *can* be done, but I beg you, don't :)

There is <strike>probably</strike> definitely a better way of implementing what you're after, but that wasn't your question, so I'll leave it at that.

**EDIT**

In fact, let me show you a better way.

```
function doFacebookStuff() {
  console.log('Hello Facebook!');
}

function doGoogleStuff() {
  console.log('Hello Google!');
}

function doYahooStuff() {
  console.log('Hello Yahoo!');
}

var domainActions = {
  'facebook.com': doFacebookStuff,
  'google.com': doGoogleStuff,
  'yahoo.com': doYahooStuff
}

var matched = Object.keys(domainActions).filter(function(domain) {
  if (linkHas(domain)) {
    domainActions[domain]();
    return true;
  }
});

console.log('matched domains:', matched);
```

You can also replace `.filter()` with `.some()`, to have it stop at the first match it finds.

Comment: Actually, the simple and straight answer is **yes**, and the longer answer is _don't do it_. JCOC611's answer shows it is possible, but there really isn't any reason to do it that way.

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer. JCOC611's answer is quite an achievement actually. I'd have never came up with that! :)

Comment: That switch statement JCOC611 wrote was amazing, although it looked a bit weird hahah.

What is domains.filter? Is that a function available within extensions? Cause it seems undefined on console.

Comment: @Ignoranian - sorry, `domains` was a typo. It should have been `domainActions` - fixed now. [`#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is a native array function in JavaScript, since ES5.

Comment: It's telling me .filter is undefined, probably because domainActions is an object instead of an array. Doesn't work on any of the major browsers I'm using. A for-in loop works though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96040/discussion-between-merott-and-ignoranian).

Answer (score 5):

Edit: **Disclaimer**: the following is something you should *not* do, but is there for reference purposes only. Don't let people tell you you *can't*, but listen when they say you *shouldn't*.

The very naive way:

```
switch(true){
    case linkHas("facebook.com"):
        // ...
        break;
    case linkHas("google.com"):
        // ...
        break;
    case linkHas("yahoo.com"):
        // ...
        break;
}
```

This has absolutely no performance benefits though. In fact, it might be slower if all the functions are evaluated before the equality tests are performed.

The long way would be to refactor `linkHas` to be `getLinkDomain` and check on whatever that returns.

In fact, lets do that. Using the convenient function [extractDomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498592/extract-root-domain-name-from-string), written by *lewdev*, you can:

```
var domain = extractDomain(link);
switch(domain){
    case "facebook.com":
        // ...
        break;
    //...
}
```

Comment: Well, you *could* do that, but c'mon, that's going to teach some nasty habits to JavaScript newbies.

Comment: @Merott made an edit. Hopefully it quenches your angst.

Comment: Thank you! It's a very clever trick what you did there, but it definitely made me cringe for a moment lol

Comment: Many thanks!! That is one weird switch statement though hahah. I think I'll go with Merott's solution instead though, because on some sites I check for specific pages and not just the domain.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an "enumeration" of domains to avoid magic strings.
2. Create a function "getDomain" that returns one of said enumeration.
3. Create your own hash table called "actions"  using an object literal, keyed on said enumeration values. Hash table values can be functions containing the logic to run for that key.

Then write:

```
actions[getDomain()]();
```

Comment: Wouldn't step 2 require an if statement?