# How to add links to images within HTML dynamically with JS?

Tags: javascript

I have 50 divs like the below, and the image is not clickable. I would like to make the image clickable, depending on what link the div contains: it is always the href link in the article_title tag.

How can I achieve this with adding just a few lines of JavaScript?

I was thinking of adding an ID to each img tag manually, and then use getElementById and do some magic, but that would take too long.

```
<div class="col-md-4 article">
      <img src="7tips.jpg" alt="Canary Wharf" title="7 Tips For Lasting In Your Career" width="324" height="235"> 
      <div class="article_category">
         <a href=”http://www.canarywharfian.co.uk/forums/wealth-management/”>Wealth Management</a> 
      </div>
      <div class="article_meta">
         <h1 class="article_title"><a href="http://www.canarywharfian.co.uk/threads/7-tips-for-lasting-in-your-career.242/" rel="bookmark" title="7 Tips For Lasting In Your Career">7 Tips For Lasting In Your Career</a></h1>
         <div class="col-md-6 author_date"><a href="http://www.canarywharfian.co.uk/members/smallcappm.1140/">SmallCapPM</a> - <span class="date"> Mar 10, 2016</span></div>
         <div class="article_abstract">
            Many of you are hoping and planning for a long and successful career in finance...
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by it would take too long?

Comment: I could save time if its only a few lines of JS

Comment: you could use a for loop

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this (using jQuery):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.block').each(function( index, value ) {
            let href = $(this).find('a[href]').attr('href');
            $(this).find('img').wrap('<a href=' + href + '></a>');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What should I put in place of "index, value"? I am asking bc I don't see them appear in the code below.

Comment: Nowhere. You may exclude them.

Comment: And instead of .block I should put in the class name right? Isn't it a problem that it's not an ID?

Comment: Its a class name because you have many of those for who you want to change stuff. Oops I made a mistake: you should wrap image with new anchor tag not change its src attribute. Let me fix it now...

Comment: Changed and tested. Now it should wrap the image in <a> tag with its href attribute.

Answer (score 0):

if you use jQuery, you can simply wrapping the images with  element.

```js
$(function(){
  // traversing all the images
  $('img').each(function(){
    // get the link by finding from parent
    var link = $(this).parent().find('.article_title a').attr('href');
    // replace the image with link + image
    $(this).replaceWith('<a href="' + link + '">' + $(this)[0].outerHTML + '</a>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 article">
      <img src="http://www.canarywharfian.co.uk/7tips.jpg" alt="Canary Wharf" title="7 Tips For Lasting In Your Career" width="324" height="235"> 
      <div class="article_category">
         <a href="http://www.canarywharfian.co.uk/forums/wealth-management/">Wealth Management</a> 
      </div>
      <div class="article_meta">
         <h1 class="article_title"><a href="http://www.canarywharfian.co.uk/threads/7-tips-for-lasting-in-your-career.242/" rel="bookmark" title="7 Tips For Lasting In Your Career">7 Tips For Lasting In Your Career</a></h1>
         <div class="col-md-6 author_date"><a href="http://www.canarywharfian.co.uk/members/smallcappm.1140/">SmallCapPM</a> - <span class="date"> Mar 10, 2016</span></div>
         <div class="article_abstract">
            Many of you are hoping and planning for a long and successful career in finance...
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: This is very good, but it returns the href in the article_category div. I need the one in the article_title.

Comment: You are a god. Thanks so much.

Comment: I have another question. Can you tell me how can I remove the "canarywharfian.co.uk" part of the href in the article_category div dynamically? I need to remove that part otherwise if a user clicks canarywharfian.co.uk/canarywharfian.co.uk/path will load which is not ok.

Comment: @D.Richard with this function, you can get the domain >> http://stackoverflow.com/a/23945027/7572603. then you just simply use that to edit href >> $('[href]').each(function(){ link = $(this).attr('href'); domain = extractDomain(link); new_href = link.replace(domain, ''); $(this).attr('href', new_href); })

Comment: This one loops through ALL the hrefs? I only need it for the first appearing one within the div.

Answer (score 0):

Per your tag of vanila Javascript, what you can do is to search for and cache all your `article`s. Within each article search for anchor inside your title and set its `href` to a newly created anchor. Append the image into the newly created anchor and prepend it into your article.

A simple example (H1 font-size reduced for demo):

```js
var articles = document.getElementsByClassName('article');

[].forEach.call(articles, function(article) {
 var image = article.querySelector('img:first-child');
 var title = article.querySelector('h1.article_title > a');
 var anchor = document.createElement('a');
 anchor.href = title.href;
 anchor.appendChild(image);
 article.insertBefore(anchor, article.firstChild);
});
```

```css
h1 { font-size: 12px; }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 article">
      <img src="//placehold.it/120x64" alt="Canary Wharf" title="7 Tips For Lasting In Your Career"> 
      <div class="article_category">
         <a href="example.com">Wealth Management</a> 
      </div>
      <div class="article_meta">
         <h1 class="article_title"><a href="//bing.com" rel="bookmark" title="7 Tips For Lasting In Your Career">7 Tips For Lasting In Your Career</a></h1>
         <div class="col-md-6 author_date"><a href="example.com">SmallCapPM</a> - <span class="date"> Mar 10, 2016</span></div>
         <div class="article_abstract">
            Many of you are hoping and planning for a long and successful career in finance...
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="col-md-4 article">
      <img src="//placehold.it/120x64" alt="Canary Wharf" title="7 Tips For Lasting In Your Career"> 
      <div class="article_category">
         <a href="example.com">Wealth Management</a> 
      </div>
      <div class="article_meta">
         <h1 class="article_title"><a href="//google.com" rel="bookmark" title="7 Tips For Lasting In Your Career">7 Tips For Lasting In Your Career</a></h1>
         <div class="col-md-6 author_date"><a href="example.com">SmallCapPM</a> - <span class="date"> Mar 10, 2016</span></div>
         <div class="article_abstract">
            Many of you are hoping and planning for a long and successful career in finance...
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Notice, how the links to bing and google are picked up from the title anchors and inserted into a new anchor wrapping the images.