# Angular 7 - extract external host name and use it to create name of an image

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to extract the domain name from my - {{video.url}}

The **{{video.url}}** contains different links like this:

```
https://domain1.com/123/abc
https://www.domain2.com/123/abc
http://www.domain3.com/123/abc
http://domain4.com/123/abc
https://www.domain5.com?123&abc
https://www.domain6.com/123/abc.html
```

I need the "domain1" "domain2" "domain3" ... and use this to create an image name under my component.ts:

```
return'https://mywebsite.com/img/'+domain+'.png';
```

The folder "/img/" will have many images named, youtube.png - google.png ...

On my angular component.html I want to add

```
<div class="video" *ngFor="let video of mediaItem.videos">
<img [src]="getIcon">
</div>
```

**But what code should I use in component.ts ???**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract hostname name from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498592/extract-hostname-name-from-string)

Comment: This is not an duplicate post, I want to use ANGULAR 7  to get the hostname from {{video.url}} - not JavaScript

Comment: using angular doesn't mean you are leaving javascript.angular has nothing to do with getting domain from a url.

Comment: can you provide stackblitz demo?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const getHost = host => {
  const hostArr = host.toLowerCase().replace(/https?:\/\//, '').split('.');
  return hostArr[0] === 'www' ? hostArr[1] : hostArr[0];
}

console.log(getHost('https://domain1.com/123/abc'));
console.log(getHost('https://www.domain2.com/123/abc'));
console.log(getHost('http://www.domain3.com/123/abc'));
console.log(getHost('http://domain4.com/123/abc'));
console.log(getHost('https://www.domain5.com?123&abc'));
console.log(getHost('https://www.domain6.com/123/abc.html'));
```

Comment: An complete code to copy/paste under my component.ts please??? I need to extract the hostname from `video.url`

Comment: It's not what I'm looking for, I want to extract the hostname directly from `video.url` This is an example of other funccion used under component.ts , in this case to open on new window the `video.url` -this- `public playVideo(video: Video) {
    if (video.type === 'external') {
        window.open(video.url, '_blank');
    } else {
        this.store.dispatch(new PlayVideo(video, this.mediaItem));
    }
}`

Comment: You can write me a code based on this example, in which the `return` will be: `return'https://mywebsite.com/img/'+domain+'.png';` - and the `'+domain+` is the hostname??? - Many thanks.