# Setting cookie in Vue.js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, middleware, setcookie

I have to set a parameter at cookies when user comes with an specific subdomain, actually there's a cookie.js script in middleware like:

```
export default function ({ app, res, query }) {
let uri = window.location.href.split('?');
if (uri[1]) {
    app.$cookies.set('pdv', query.pdv)
}}
```

I have to keep this feature, but when user comes from subdomain e.g: ask.exemple.com, automatically sets the PDV cookies as: 123.

E.g:

subdomain: ask / pdv: 123
subdomain: question / pdv: 456
...

How can I do it?

Comment: see: [How to get a subdomain using window.location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201258/how-to-get-a-subdomain-using-window-location), then apply it to the code above

Comment: Thanks!! What do you think about it: 

export default function ({ app, res, query }) {
    let uri = window.location.href.split('?');
    if (uri[1]) {
        app.$cookies.set('pdv', query.pdv)
    }

    let sub = window.location.host.split('.');
    if (sub['confianca']) {
        app.$cookies.set('pdv', 'IMCI68')
    }

    else if (sub['metropole']) {
        app.$cookies.set('pdv', 'JK1TC7')
    }

     else if (sub['radiocultura']) {
        app.$cookies.set('pdv', 'J79KO9')
    }
}